# How to search an array within a structure using bsearch in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, bsearch

Please help I don't understand why I can't search an element in an array within a structure to another array within another structure.
Thank you for your help guys would really appreciate it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

typedef struct{
    int elements[MAX];
    int count;
}SET;

int cmpfunc(const void * a, const void * b) {
   return (*(int*)a > *(int*)b) - (*(int*)a < *(int*)b);
}

void print(SET *s1, SET *s2){
    int *p;
    p = bsearch(&s2->elements[1],&s1->elements,s1->count,sizeof(s1->elements),cmpfunc);
    printf("%p",p);

    return;
}

int main () {
    SET s1 = {{5,20,29,32,63},5};
    SET s2 = {{1,29,3,5},4};

    print(&s1,&s2);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: you should enhance your question with expected result and maybe explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
sizeof(*s1->elements)
```

that is the same as

```
sizeof( int )
```

instead of

```
sizeof(s1->elements)
```

in the call of `bsearch`.

Also instead of

```
&s1->elements
```

use

```
s1->elements
```

The call will look like

```
bsearch( &s2->elements[1], s1->elements, s1->count, sizeof(*s1->elements), cmpfunc );
```

Pay attention to that the conversion specifier `%x` may not be used with pointers. Use either `%p` or dereference the found pointer and use `%x` provided that the target value is found.

Comment: Thank you very much sir @Vlad it just solved my problem. ^_^